# At what value of x each of the functions below are Not differentiable? Explain. Function: f(x) = | x -2 |

Tags: derivatives

Please try to use derivatives laws in your answer. Otherwise answer freely.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a plot of this function:
[image: Image of plot]

Notice that for $x<2$, $f'(x)=-1$ and for $x>2$, $f'(x)=1$. If we look at this closer we get:
$$f'(2)=\lim_{x\to\ 2^-}f(x)=-1$$
$$f'(2)=\lim_{x\to 2^+}f(x)=1$$
These values are clearly not the same so: $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)$ does not exist, the function is not differentiable at this point

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Differentiability is a *smoothness* condition on the curve of the function.

$$f(x)=\mid x-2\mid=\begin{cases}+(x-2) \ , \ x\ge2 \\ -(x-2)\ , \ x\lt 2\end{cases}$$

Clearly the function is a linear function for $(-\infty, 2)\ \cup\ (2,\infty)$. So only cause of trouble can be at $x=2$. Notice that $$\begin{aligned}f'(2)=\lim_{x\to 2^+}=-1 \\ f'(2)=\lim_{x\to 2^-}=+1\end{aligned}$$

Since $f'(2^+)\ne f'(2^-)$. Hence $f(x)=\mid x-2 \ \mid $ is not differentiable at $x=2$.